# css overflow-y:auto not working in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have the following code

```
<div id="someDiv" style="float: right; margin-right: -350px; position: relative; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;">
<svg class="someSvgClass" width="105">
<g>..</g>
<g>..</g>
...
</svg>
</div>
```

This div contains inside another div with a fixed height.These "g" elements are added dynamically using JavaScript.
So I expect a scroll bar when the no of "g" elements is increased

In IE11 I could able to see the scroll bar when the no of "g" elements are high. But for the same no of elements I was not able to see scroll bar in Firefox and in chrome 
anyone please tell me what is gone wrong here
here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ngpn59x/1/)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: If the overflow attribute has a value other than hidden or scroll, the property has no effect. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow

Comment: @GermanoPlebani We are talking about [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) and [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)

Comment: @Siguza i assume overflow and overflow-x or y have the same restriction in this case because in the complete reference is not present -x or -y

Comment: @GermanoPlebani I just realized your link was for SVG attributes... we're talking about CSS, btw. And no, `overflow` and `overflow-x/y` do certainly **not** have the same "restrictions", as you can clearly see by clicking one of my links - the possible values are listed there.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani i added the svg group into a div since svg doesn't have support of overflow....and i'm giving overflow attributes for the div

Comment: @all and i was able to see scroll bar in IE11 but not in either firefox nor in chrome

Comment: @Zee and all question is updated with sample fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an SVG expert, i never used it, but seems SVG doesn't change height. If you set height to the SVG it works: http://jsfiddle.net/u5ymhmht/7/

The practical solution in your js when you add a line, add height of the line to SVG.

p.s. Sorry for the previous misunderstanding.

```css
svg {
    height:500px;
}

#Someid {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="Someid">
    <svg  width="105">
    <g transform="translate(10,5)">
            <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,20)">
            <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,35)">
        <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,50)">
            <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,65)">
        <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,80)">
            <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        
        <g transform="translate(10,95)">
        <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,110)">
            <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        
        <g transform="translate(10,125)">
        <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,140)">
            <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        
        <g transform="translate(10,155)">
        <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,170)">
            <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,185)">
        <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(10,200)">
            <text style="fill: black;" dy=".35em" y="5" x="15">asdsd</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```